# How to solve a list indexi error in python

Tags: python, list

Hellor pythoneers,

I was doing a python program where it reads a group of circles of a file and, once it demands information to the user of a certain circle, determine whether this circle is an inner circumference, an outer circumference or a secant one.

However, i'm experiencing an error I've never seen before.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Exercici.py", line 68, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:\Exercici.py", line 41, in main
    x=io.obtReal(i)
  File "d:\modul_lect_escr.py", line 93, in obtReal    
    return float(sequencia[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know for a fact the error is in this line of code:

```
def main():
    M=20
    N=3
    mat=np.zeros((M,N),float)
    nomf="circumferencies.txt"
    io.obrirFitxer(nomf)
    i=0
   
    x=io.obtReal(i)      <------
    y=io.obtReal(i)      <------ Error
    radi=io.obtReal(i)   <------

    while not(x==-999.999 and y==999.999 and radi==999.999):
        i=i+1
        mat[i,0]=x
        mat[i,1]=y
        mat[i,2]=radi

        x=io.obtReal(i)
        y=io.obtReal(i)
        radi=io.obtReal(i)

    num_circumferencies=i
```

The function called obtReal comes from a library I was given to read files. Here's the extract of the function:

```
def obtReal(i):                   #  1st test ok  
    return float(sequencia[i])
```

If anyone has any clue to where the error is, I'd love to hear their opinion.

Comment: the first call is `obtReal(0)` so it is looking at index 0 in the list `sequencia` (which seems to be a global variable ?). So, assuming this library of yours work fine and fills up the `sequencia` variable correctly, it may be your text file is empty, or that its content can't be parsed with your library.

Comment: The error means the index `i` is outside the size of your `sequencia` list.

Comment: If there error takes place in the while loop, it is possible you are increasing the value of `i` too much. But if you are right about the line where the error takes place, my previous statement stands.

Comment: We need to set the code where sequencia is constructed/added to if we are to know why it doesn't contain as many elements as requested.